# Sum of all custom fields for category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I've got a custom field on posts called `number`.

On the front-end in category.php, I need to total up the value of all posts in the current category that have `number`.

So for example, if the current category had 3 posts, and in each post the `number` values were `1`, `5` and `10` respectively, then on the front-end it needs to display the total `16`.

I'm not entirely sure where to start with this.

The loop I have at the moment:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <h1><?php printf( __( 'Category Archives: %s', 'twentythirteen' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) ); ?></h1>
        <p></p>

    <?php /* The loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <?php // ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: show what you got in `category.php`

Comment: What happens when you get the fields and add them?

Comment: @Viral - It's the default category.php page. Nothing special about it.

Comment: @mevius - That is what I need to do. Get the "number" field on each post for the current category, and total them up to display the total on category.php

Comment: is that you having got 3 arrays of query in total for example now, and you don't konw how to separate the `number` of each array and sum?

Comment: [get_field()](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) in your loop for each post, and then increment a variable `+=`

Comment: @rnevius awesome. Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: No, I have no idea what your loop looks like, as you haven't added that info to your question.

Comment: @rnevius - Sorry! I missed that in your previous comment. Original post updated to show the loop I have. Ideally the total number would end up in the empty <p> tag.

Comment: As you need this outside the loop on top, I think a great idea will be to write a static function using `$wp_query->posts` , a `foreach` loop, and `get_post_meta`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. There was a lot there that helped me arrive at this solution (and a little help from Google):

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'offset' => 0, 
    'category' => $category
);
$numbers = get_posts( $args );

$total = 0;
foreach( $numbers as $numbersID ) {
    $single = get_post_meta( $numbersID->ID, 'numbers', true );
    $total += $single;
}
echo $total;
?>
```

The key was knowing to increment a variable += as @rnevius suggested, which I didn't know about.

Comment: Don't run another query, it is expensive, use `$wp_query->posts`, all your posts are stored there. Instead of `$numbers = get_posts( $args );`, do `$numbers = $wp_query->posts`

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version of what you're trying to achieve (which also reduces calls to the database) would look something like the following:

```
<p>
    <?php
        $total = 0;
        foreach( $wp_query->posts as $number ) {
            $total += get_post_meta( $number->ID, 'numbers', true );
        }
        echo $total;
    ?>
</p>
```

As mentioned in another comment, you don't need another loop, as your posts already exist in `$wp_query`.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was talking about. At least someone read my comments :-)

Answer (score -2):

Supposing you're using MySQL use [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) Method to achive your goals. Query might look something like `SELECT SUM(number) FROM category WHERE [drill down to a specific set of categories if neccesary];`

Comment: Why is my answer downvoted? When i posted it, there was no code attached in the question so i had to make assumptions.