# Sum of custom field value from all posts

Tags: wordpress

I refered former QA [Sum of all custom fields for category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772772/sum-of-all-custom-fields-for-category), and tried following 2 codes, but no result returned.  Somebody knows what is wrong with these codes?

This code returns 0.

```
<?php    
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'cat'  => '771',  
);
$wp_query->posts;
$total = 0;
foreach( $numbers as $numbersID ) {
$single = get_post_meta( $numbersID->ID, 'price', true );
$total += $single;
}
echo $total;
?>
```

This code also returns 0.

```
<?php
$total = 0;
foreach( $wp_query->posts as $number ) {
$total += get_post_meta( $number->ID, 'price', true );
}
echo $total;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try forcing the value returned by `get_post_meta` and testing if meta exists

```
if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $number->ID, 'price' ) ) {
    $total += (int)get_post_meta( $number->ID, 'price', true );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise.  Looks like nothing is returned.  Maybe this means no meta data exists...Thank you. @Sco